# MySQL for Visual Studio,unable to load the stored procedure for editing

Tags: mysql, database, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Unfortunately it is not possible to debug Stored Procedures mySQL for Visual Studio. When I click on a Stored Procedure, a window with the error message *"Unable to load the stored procedure for editing"* always appears. The connection is established and it is possible to change or query views, for example. I can even create procedures, but editing after that is no longer possible. I tried the Versions of MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.7 and MySQL for Visual Studio 2.0.5 m4 on Visual Studio 2015 and 2017, and SQL Server version 8.0 and 5.7.19, but the problem persisted.

Comment: Have you been able to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

You should modify connection on your Server Explorer And then check on checkbox "Save my password"

[You should modify connection on your Server Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONktR.png)

[And then check on checkbox "Save my password"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXrK6.png)